# How to call VieModel function on custom binding Knockout Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

How can I call a ViewModel function inside of a custom binding? I have a custom binding to apply jQuery Validate to a form and I need to call a function in the submitHandler, but nothing I've tried so far works. Can someone point me in the right direction? I've read the documentation, but it's not very clear on the subject.

Here is my custom knockout binding

```
// activate the jQuery Validate on the form
 ko.bindingHandlers.validateEmailForm = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {      
        $(element).validate({
            errorLabelContainer: $("#updateEmailFormAlert"),
            wrapper: 'li',
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            return $("#emailConfirm").is(":filled");
                        }
                    },
                    email: true
                },
                emailConfirm: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            return $("#email").is(":filled");
                        }
                    },
                    email: true,
                    equalTo: "#email",
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Email is required",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                },
                emailConfirm: {
                    required: "Confirm Email is required",
                    email: "Please enter a valid confirm email address",
                    equalTo: "Confirm Email must match Email"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function() {

                bindingContext.$root.updateUserEmail;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can access the viewModel pretty easily from the custom binding. The current context's viewModel is passed in the viewModel variable, and if you need to access anything else, the bindingContext has access to all parent binding contexts, up until $root.

So if you want to call a function from the viewModel, just do `viewModel.someFunction()` .

It appears you are already doing something in the submitHandler (`bindingContext.$root.updateUserEmail`) Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: its not working...when I call bindingContext.$root.updateUserEmail, the page reloads and nothing updates, so the function isn't getting called.

Comment: And if you add () at the end, like bindingContext.$root.updateUserEmail() ?

Comment: same thing...and if I can't get this to work...no more jQuery validate...which kinda sucks. Should be easier to get call a method on the viewmodel form a custom binding.

Comment: So what happens when you call the function, do you get any error in the console?